# angular 4 splice always deletes last element from array

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a weird problem where for some reason splice always deletes last element from array, even though the `alert` gives correct index.

The `onRemove()` method is what does the removing.

```
<button (click)="onAdd()">Add</button>

<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let course of courses; index as i; even as isEven">
        {{ i }} - {{ course.name }} <span *ngIf="isEven">(EVEN)</span>
        <button (click)="onRemove(course)">Remove</button>
    </li>
</ul>

export class AppComponent {

    courses = [
        { id: 1, name: 'course1' },
        { id: 2, name: 'course2' },
        { id: 3, name: 'course3' },
    ];

    onAdd() {
        this.courses.push({ id: 4, name: 'course4' });
    }

    onRemove(course) {
        let index = this.courses.indexOf(course);
        alert(index); // I get correct index here
        this.courses.splice(index, 1);
    }

}
```

Comment: are you sure you're not looking at `{{i}}` and think it's `{{course.id}}`? The code is working fine http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is correct. I think the angle you are looking at it could be the problem. It is removing the correct element when you click on it.

For example, consider that you have 3 elements in the array with the following contexts index starting from 0.

```
  0 - course1
  1 - course2 
  2 - course3
```

When You remove element with index 1, the total number of elements becomes two and as a result the index changes as well.

```
0 - course1 
1 - course3
```

So this can get you to think that it is always deleting the last element whereas in reality it is just shifting the position of the array.

The following code could be what you are trying to achieve. Just change the first string interpolation to `{{course.id}}` instead of `{{i}}`

```
<li *ngFor="let course of courses; index as i; even as isEven">
    {{ course.id }} - {{ course.name }} <span *ngIf="isEven">(EVEN)</span>
    <button (click)="onRemove(course)">Remove</button>
</li>
```

Hope this helps