# splice always delete last item from an array

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried a lot searching for, how to delete array item giving its index postion but in vain.
Splice always remove last item from an array though I supply the index position of the item which needs to be deleted.(Here I know which index position of an item which is to be deleted. Following is my code.

```
//Array declaration and value assignment

  let a: Product = {} as any;
  a.id='E001';
  a.name='EarPhone';
  a.price='230$';
  a.qty='20';
  a.tax='10.222';
  a.total='2222.22';
  this.product.push(a);  //pushing data to product array
  a.id='E002';
  a.name='HeadPhone';
  a.price='230$';
  a.qty='20';
  a.tax='10.222';
  a.total='2222.22';
  this.product.push(a);
  a.id='E003';
  a.name='MicroPhone';
  a.price='230$';
  a.qty='20';
  a.tax='10.222';
  a.total='2222.22';
  this.product.push(a);

/*   Required: Now i want to delete data in index position 1 that is 'E002', for which i have used slice function like this.
*/


//code to delete array item of particular index
void deletedItem()
{
//INDEX POSITION IS ONE HERE
this.product.splice(indexPosition,1);
}
```

But it always delete item in the last index that is product with id='E003';

Note: The link below doesn't give the answer I am looking for
[angular 4 splice always deletes last element from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46110228/angular-4-splice-always-deletes-last-element-from-array)

Comment: how do u set `indexPosition` or are u passing it in `deletedItem` function ?

Comment: to be precise i know the index postion the item of which need to be deleted.

Comment: This code deosn't make sense: you're adding a single object three times in the array.

Comment: can u log it and verify that `indexPosition` is 1 ?

Comment: I have an event associated with row which gives me an index position, which further is used to delete the item from the array

Comment: Try to log `indexPosition` before the splice function to see if it is having the correct value

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you fell into the *'counter-variable in a loop with asynchronous events'* trap:

example:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    var el = createElement(...);
    el.on('click', ()=> deleteItem(i));
}
```

In this case, when click is executed, i will be 10, because the loop has finished before the deleteItem has been called

There are different ways to avoid this. Imho, the most elegant solution is to move the loop code into a different method or function:

```
function createRow(i) {
    // i will always be the value you passed as parameter, so the value at the time of the row creation.
    var el = createElement(...);
    el.on('click', ()=> deleteItem(i));
}
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    createRow(i);
}
```

**Edit:**
To clarify what happens here.. this is called closure. See also:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

The code execution happens as follows:

- declare i=0
- loop 10 times and add listeners to the elements
- during this loop, i gets incremented.
- finally at some point, someone clicks on an element
- the onclick function gets called.
- the onclick looks at variable i, which is now 10 (since the loop has finished)

Functions have access to variables in their surrounding scope. They don't get a copy of **i**, they get an actual reference. They can read (its latest value) and even change the value of **i**.

Comment: Thanks for answer, can you explain a little more please:  `In this case, when click is executed, i will be 10, because the loop has finished before the deleteItem has been called` why `i` fails to be the loop number since the element is create at a certain account I assume

Comment: @Webwoman I've updated my answer with a more detailed explanation, since this comment field is good enough for that. Hope it helps.